# Mysql query for sum data

Tags: mysql

I want to make a report with MYSQL from this data

Table name: table

```
date name Quantity
13 Nov Rudy 40
13 Nov Mery 30
13 Nov Rudy 20
13 Nov John 10
14 Nov Rudy 20
14 Nov Rudy 30
```

I want the result like this

```
13 Nov Rudy 60
13 Nov Mery 30
13 Nov John 10
14 Nov Rudy 50
```

What query should I do?

thanks

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hint `... SUM(Quantity) ...  GROUP BY date, name`

Comment: @RaymondNijland does mysql has support for including 2 columns for `group by`?

Comment: Thanks mate, it works.

Comment: @marmeladze yes offcource. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html BNF  `[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position} [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]`

Comment: You should see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if mysql has support for 2 columns in `group by` clause, so grouping by `date + user` should work. but if it has, you can skip this trick and replace this clause with `(group by date name)` as @RaymondNijland proposed.

```
select date, name, sum(quantity) as total 
from your_table 
group by concat(date, "_", name);
```